# Using a Struct Inside of a Function

Tags: function, class, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have a struct, file, and a class with functions in it. I'm trying to create a linked list of structs in my function, but I can't quite understand how to go about doing it! Here's my work thus far for that portion of my code:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

class myPrintSpool
{
public:
    void send(string);

private:
    int printSpoolSize;
    myPrintSpool *printSpoolHead;
    myPrintSpool* next;
};

struct file
{
    string fileName;
    int filePriority;
    file* next;
};

void myPrintSpool::send(string name)
{
    //Adds to linked list
    file file;

    myPrintSpool* file = new myPrintSpool;

    if(printSpoolHead == NULL)
    {
        printSpoolHead = file;
    }
    else
    {
        file->next = printSpoolHead;
        printSpoolHead = file;
    }

    printSpoolSize++;
}
```

I send a string inside the function so that when the user inputs a file name to send, it changes the name of the struct to that fileName in struct file changes to that input name. However, I'm not sure what to do since I cannot get the above portion to work properly first.

Thank you in advance, and thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: How many more times do you want to say `file`? Can't you come up with some slightly more unique names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done any C++, so this is all from recollection. In the code you supplied, you aren't instantiating a class. You are allocating memory for one.
If you want to assign a new class to that memory:

```
myPrintSpool printSpool = new myPrintSpool();
myPrintSpool *file = &printSpool;
```

I'm somewhat confused as to what you are actually doing. It seems the printSpoolHead will always be equal to the current myPrintSpool object, and if it's anything other than the first instantiation, it points back to itself.

As you didn't say anything specific as to the location of your error(s), do a simple output to verify the function is doing what you think it should (or is) doing.

Edit: Actually, I recall being thrown off by C++ instantiation, so it may be:

```
myPrintSpool printSpool;
```